# Drupal 7 drupal_mail stripping out HTML?

Tags: php, html, drupal, sendmail, content-type

I have a custom module that I'm trying to generate an HTML email from using the drupal_mail function (D7). Mail is coming through, and even shows text/html, however something somewhere appears to be stripping out the HTMl before it gets to an inbox.

First, in a function I'm building my title/body/other vars and sending to a custom function:

```
    $body = "We thought you'd like to know that ".$fullname." has marked your project as completed.
    <br /><br />
    Please visit the link at <a href='http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/survey/customer/".$customer[0]->unique_id."'>http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/survey/customer/".$customer[0]->unique_id."</a> to take the survey.";
    $returnMail = latch_send_mail('pro_realized',$customer[0]->customer_email,$user->mail,$title,$body);
```

Then I have the latch_mail latch_send_email functions:

```
function latch_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
    $headers = array(
    'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
    'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8Bit',
    'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal'
);

foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
    $message['headers'][$key] = $value;
}

$message['body'][] = $params['body'];
$message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
}
```

and

```
function latch_send_mail($key,$to,$from,$title,$body,$headers='') {
    $params['body']=$body;
    $params['subject'] = t($title);
    return drupal_mail('latch', $key, $to, language_default(), $params, $from,TRUE);
}
```

I would expect the emails to come through with my a tags and br tags, but it comes through like this:

```
We thought you'd like to know that John Doe has marked your project as completed. Please visit the link at http://latch.local/survey/customer/34c91b8883cd70b32c65feb7adf9c393 [1] to take the survey. [1] http://latch.local/survey/customer/34c91b8883cd70b32c65feb7adf9c393
```

Somehow it's taking my links and turning them into footnotes while removing the br tags completely.

Any help you can provide would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box, Drupal can't send HTML email. In order for Drupal to support HTML email you need the HTML Mail module. http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail  Once you have that all HTML should be sent as such.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative method with a complete explenation. First of all, install and enable the [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) module. You can read the [README.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/mimemail/tree/README.txt) for complete instructions on how to use it. I'll give you the short version.

You need to enable Mime Mail for your module. You can do this using `hook_enable` or `hook_update_N` in `example.install`:

```
function example_enable() {
  mailsystem_set(array(
    'example_examplekey' => 'MimeMailSystem',
  ));
}
```

When you go to `admin/config/system/mailsystem` you will see that a new entry has been added for your module:

> Example module (examplekey key) class
>
> MimeMailSystem

Now you don't need to specificy any `text/html` headers anymore, Mime Mail takes care of this. So you don't need this:

```
$headers['Content-Type'] = ...
```

If you want, you can add `$message['plaintext']` to your mail for a non-HTML alternative, but this is not required.

That's it!

Comment: I already had Mime Mail installed, this was the last piece I was missing to get emails to display full HTML. Thanks!